# Bower: exit code of #128 fatal

Tags: git, npm, bower

I have this problem. it happens with random libraries:

```
bower angular-route-segment#^1.3.0  ECMDERR Failed to execute      "git ls-remote --tags --heads            git://github.com/artch/angular-route-segment.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/artch/angular-route-segment.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

This decision not solved my problem:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

If i trying clone repo directly, it's done!

```
sasha@sasha-GA-MA770T-UD3:~$ git clone  git://github.com/angular- ui/bootstrap.git
Cloning into 'bootstrap'...
remote: Counting objects: 7101, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 7101 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 7080
Receiving objects: 100% (7101/7101), 5.23 MiB | 1.56 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3308/3308), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most DNS servers have DoS protection which limits the amount of DNS requests in X amount of time. My internet provider is one of them.

I changed DNS servers (which I received from my internet provider) to Google DNS services and it solved my problem.